# convert the time domain signal into frequency domain signal

Tags: time, dns, frequency

I have represented the acceleration data of 3 axes(x, y, and z) in time domain as shown in the Graph

[image]

I would like to extract from the acceleration data some measurements (e.g. mean, energy, entropy and correlation) in the frequency domain. Therefore, I applied FFT transform in order to convert the time domain signal into frequency domain signal.

```
 xx=  fft(x_Segments{1});
plot(xx)
yy=  fft(y_Segments{1});
plot(yy)
 zz=  fft(z_Segments{1});
 plot(zz)
```

However, the resulted graphs make no sense( so strange) which is not expected at all !! This is an example of the frequency domain signal of the x-axis.

[image]

Note, x_Segments, y_Segments, and z_Segments contain the data of X, Y, Z axes in the time domain respectively.

As we can see the graph doesn't make sense, so, is there any steps that I should follow before using the FFT function to get the expected frequency domain signal?

I really appreciate your help guys. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mostly a math problem

Comment: It's off topic because there's no code here - no programming (yet).  You have  to grok the math, first.  You have to understand that the output of an FFT is a set of _complex numbers_, with the magnitude and _relative phase_ of each harmonic encoded therein.